# How to query a custom dimension with GA4 using jdbc driver?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to query some custom dimensions using JDBC driver for GA4.
If I check the metadata API I can see that one of the custom dimensions is customUser:dimension1

But when I try to query it I returns the following error:

- Query; SELECT Date, conversions, dimensions FROM "GoogleAnalytics4"."Engagement" where Dimensions='customUser:dimension1' and Date='20230510'

Error:

[image]

Does any know which is the issue? Seems that it understands that a dimension is called customUser:dimension1 because if I query something random like customUser:random it outputs the same error.

[image]